# Query hangs on forever with grouping

Tags: mysql

we can't get this simple query working:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT  h.*, h.NewValue AS STATUS,
         (SELECT h2.CreatedDate
          FROM siebel_service_request_history h2
          WHERE h2.Field = 'Status' AND h2.CreatedDate > h.CreatedDate AND
                h2.SiebelID = h.SiebelID
          ORDER BY h2.CreatedDate
          LIMIT 1
         ) AS nextCreatedDate
  FROM siebel_service_request_history h WHERE h.Field ='Status') h

  GROUP BY h.SiebelID, h.Status
```

It works fine with grouping by `SiebelID` (but slow) and does hung like forever if we add grouping by `Status`. But we need both of fields included in grouping in order to get data we want.

We have exactly the same query running and working for salesforce_case_history table (it runs very fast and to be exact we have approximately the same number of records in both tables (salesforce_case_history - -- 1159870 records VS siebel_service_request_history – 1202865 records)):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT h.*, h.NewValue AS STATUS,
         (SELECT h2.CreatedDate
          FROM salesforce_case_history h2
          WHERE h2.Field = 'Status' AND h2.CreatedDate > h.CreatedDate AND
                h2.CaseId = h.CaseId
          ORDER BY h2.CreatedDate
          LIMIT 1
         ) AS nextCreatedDate
  FROM salesforce_case_history h WHERE h.Field ='Status'
 ) h
GROUP BY h.CaseId, h.Status
```

We also created the same composite index on `siebel_service_request_history` for inner sub-select searching including three fields (`SiebelID`, `CreatedDate`, `Field`) table as we have created on salesforce_case_history. We tried almost everything we knew but unfortunately didn't come up with the root problem of this issue.

Comment: Because you are selecting from `h`, which is a "table" you made on-the-fly, it has no indices. You are not getting any speed in that group-by from any index you make, because you re-create the table you're grouping everytime you query.

Comment: why to downvote ?? as far as i think the question is good

Comment: It could be because you just dump a query that is slow. No "this is my goal", no explanation of the problem, just "this query is slow". As per my comment (I think), it is logical that it is slow, but I cannot actually answer your question, because I have no clue what you want. You probably need a structural re-write of the query. This means that the question in its current form isn't clear.

Comment: @Nanne: that doesn't explain why it works fast and convenient for one table and does not for another (amount of records as I mentioned is the same and even tables structures are).

Comment: Nope it doesn't, but it is true, and a fact you really need to take into account optimizing this query. Again, I know it is not an answer, but I thought it might help you. Anyway, there could be all sorts of reasons for the inconsistency, but as we know _nothing_ of your system or the contents, it's kinda hard to say more.

Comment: For the problem we're solving the query is optimized at its most possible version, except we can retrieve not all but less records, however that's not helpful at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
SELECT  h.*, h.NewValue AS STATUS,
         (SELECT h2.CreatedDate
          FROM siebel_service_request_history h2
          WHERE h2.Field = 'Status' AND h2.CreatedDate > h.CreatedDate AND
                h2.SiebelID = h.SiebelID
          ORDER BY h2.CreatedDate
          LIMIT 1
         ) AS nextCreatedDate
  FROM siebel_service_request_history h WHERE h.Field ='Status'

  GROUP BY h.SiebelID, h.Status
```

you had an extra not necessary subquery step.

Also try creating a table from the subquery, adding indices on what you group by, then group the select * from table. will be substantially faster, I use temp tables with indices in all my routines.

Comment: AdrianBR:you rock! that was a problem! now we will use transitive tables for our purposes, thanx

Comment: also we added composite index on (SiebelID,NewValue) included in grouping, however it's still a mystery why it works as it was for one table but doesn't for another.

Comment: it's about how mysql chooses to order. If you look into explains (explain select...), there is probably a sort happening in the slower query. an alternative trick is to group by calculated columns such as group by id+0 or group by left(status, 255). this will usually slow things down, but sometimes it avoids unwanted sorts.